# Looking for Python in GIS talk/tutorial submissions for pyArkansas Python conference

Tags: discussion

The [Call for Proposals](http://www.pyarkansas.org/speaking/cfp/) for [pyArkansas 2012](http://www.pyarkansas.org/) is currently underway. We would really, really love to see some talks and tutorials on Python and GIS. The conference is in its 5th year now and will once again be [held on the campus](http://www.pyarkansas.org/venue/) of the University of Central Arkansas, this year on October 27th. The conference will be free to attend. If any has any questions, please feel free to post them here or my contact info can be found on the pyArkansas [About page](http://www.pyarkansas.org/about/staff/).

Comment: Please post this announcement at http://meta.gis.stackexchange.com/questions/540/community-promotion-ads-2012, Chad.

Comment: Will do @whuber. Thought about that but wasn't sure of the appropriateness. Thanks.

Comment: Done. http://meta.gis.stackexchange.com/a/865/65